# Copying cells with formulas changes the number in the formula instead of the letter

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to copy a row with formulas that call another sheet, so for instance `=Sheet2!G3`

When I try to copy this row to create a new one, the formulas change to `=Sheet2!G4`.

How can I copy these cells so that the formula changes only the letter? So in this case it should be `=Sheet2!H3`

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [absolute and relative references](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```
How can I copy these cells so that the formula changes only the letter?
```

You can always **lock the row using the `$` sign**

`=Sheet2!G$3`

Comment: Thanks, that is already one step done! Do you by any chance also know how to increase the letter if you copy the cell to the next one? So G would be H.

Comment: *"Do you by any chance..."*. I think you are just repeating your question. Do I miss something? Have you tried my suggestion? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and it only solved half of my problem. It makes sure that the copied cell doesn’t go a number higher. The thing I still need is that copying it will increase the letter by 1.